# Can't make listview it said array null

Tags: android

I want to display contacts that I get from API using listview. But when I want to run it, it forced close. When I try to look the log that I made, the usernamefriendprofile array is null outside the response. Otherwise, the usernamefriendprofile array had a value inside the response. If I put the array adapter in response it get an error like

> Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(anonymous com.androidnetworking.interfaces JSONObject RequestListener, int, int, java.util.ArrayList)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private TextView username;
public String tokenUser;
public JSONObject namaTeman;
public String namaUser;
public JSONArray friends;
private TextView usernameFriends;
ArrayList<String> usernameFriendsProfile = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView teman;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tokenUser= getIntent().getStringExtra("token");
    Log.d(TAG, "tokenmainactivity" + tokenUser); //untuk log pada onerror
    Log.d(TAG, "tokenhalamanselanjutnya " + tokenUser);
    username = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.user);
    usernameFriends = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameTeman);
    teman=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.teman);
    initData();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_listview,R.id.usernameTeman,usernameFriendsProfile);
    teman.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "usernametemendiluar : " + usernameFriendsProfile);

}




public void initData() {
    //get user
    AndroidNetworking.get("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users")
            .addHeaders("Authorization","Bearer "+tokenUser)
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response); //untuk log pada onresponse
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                        String usernameAkun = obj.getString("username");
                        username.setText(usernameAkun);
                        Log.d(TAG, "namaprofil : " + username);
                        JSONArray friends = obj.getJSONArray("friends");

                        for (int i=0;i<friends.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject objek = friends.getJSONObject(i);
                            usernameFriendsProfile.add(objek.getString("username"));
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "usernametemendidalem : " + usernameFriendsProfile);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: Failed" + error); //untuk log pada onerror
                }
            });
}


}
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

as @Josep said change this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
```

to :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

and move this block :

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_listview,R.id.usernameTeman,usernameFriendsProfile);
teman.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

to the end of `onResponse` method.

You are fetching data asynchronously so the code inside the `onResponse` will be execute after the initialization of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your class variables a bit:

```
ArrayList<String> usernameFriendsProfile = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tokenUser= getIntent().getStringExtra("token");
    Log.d(TAG, "tokenmainactivity" + tokenUser); //untuk log pada onerror
    Log.d(TAG, "tokenhalamanselanjutnya " + tokenUser);
    username = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.user);
    usernameFriends = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameTeman);
    teman=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.teman);

    // initialize the ArrayList here
    usernameFriendsProfile = new ArrayList<String>();

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_listview,R.id.usernameTeman,usernameFriendsProfile);
    teman.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    initData();
    Log.d(TAG, "usernametemendiluar : " + usernameFriendsProfile);
}
```

I made the `Adapter` a class variable. But, there are other approaches you can take.

Then inside the response notify the `Adapter` that the data has been updated:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response); //untuk log pada onresponse
    try {
        String usernameAkun = response.getString("username");
        username.setText(usernameAkun);
        Log.d(TAG, "namaprofil : " + username);

        JSONArray friends = response.getJSONArray("friends");

        for (int i=0;i<friends.length();i++){
            JSONObject objek = friends.getJSONObject(i);
            usernameFriendsProfile.add(objek.getString("username"));
        }
        // notify the adapter that the data has been updated
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.d(TAG, "usernametemendidalem : " + usernameFriendsProfile);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

instead of

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
```

when creating the JSONObject.